# HttpClientのDefaultRequestHeaders.Addにて「Misused header name」となる

Tags: c#

https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f3039523b

を参考にC＃にてFace APIを使用する処理を作成しているのですが、
この「Code samples」の

```
// Request headers
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "{subscription key}");
```

の部分にて
{"Misused header name. Make sure request headers are used with HttpRequestMessage, response headers with HttpResponseMessage, and content headers with HttpContent objects."}
という例外になります。

サンプルのコードがおかしいのでしょうか？それともほかに要因があるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

`HttpClient`はヘッダーの意味ごとに設定すべき個所が異なります。これは`POST`しないのに`Content-Type`ヘッダーが含まれるというような矛盾を発生させないためです。

```
// Request body
byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{body}");

using (var content = new ByteArrayContent(byteData))
{
   content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("< your content type, i.e. application/json >");
   response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
}
```

の部分は

```
using (var content = new StringContent("{body}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
    response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
```

と書くことでrequest bodyの`Content-Type`ヘッダーを設定できます。

Comment: // Request body　の部分ではなく、Headerのところですでに例外となってしまうのですが、
そこはバッサリ不要ということなのでしょうか？

Comment: それはPOSTのためでしょうか。GETで使いたければどうしたらContenttype設定できるのでしょうか